# waiting thread/s until onther thread/s ends c++ linux OS

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, mutex, armadillo

I have three functions in my project written in c++,in the same .cpp file and i have two .h files.
now, i have three corresponding threads so that,the 2nd thread takes the output from the 1st thread,and the last thread waits until the 2nd thread end its operations.note that the threads are with in a "forever loop" i.e.while(1){....}

`//source.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "source.h"
#include "glob_variables.h"
#include "armadillo"
#include <vector>
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

void source::first_function(int size)
{
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
   container.push_back(i);//container is global variable vector of type int declared in glob_variables.h
  }
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void source::second_function()
{
   //sleep until the first function fills the the vector to set set its size to matrix.n_rows 
  matrix.set_size(container.size(),33);
   for(int i=0;i<container.size();i++)
   {
    for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
     {
       matrix(i,j)=i+j;//matrix is also a global variable in glob_variables.h
     }
   }
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void source::third_function()
{
//sleep untill the second function fills the matrix, then print
cout<<matrix;//print out the matrix
}
```

//source.h

```
#include "glob_variables.h"
#include "armadillo"
#include <vector>
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;
class source
{
public:
 void first_function(int size);
 void second_function();
 void third_function();
};
```

//glob_variables.h

```
#include "armadillo"
#include <vector>
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

extern mat matrix;
extern vector<int> container;
```

//Main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include "source.h"
    #include "glob_variables.h"
    #include "armadillo"
    #include <vector>
    using namespace arma;
    using namespace std;

//thread functions
     void* first_reader(void* id1)
     {
       source mysource;
       while(1)
       {
         mysource.first_function(80);
       }
     }

     void* second_reader(void* id2)
     {
       source mysource;
       while(1)
       {
         mysource.second_function();
       }
     }

     void* third_reader(void* id3)
     {
       source mysource;
       while(1)
       {
        mysource.third_function();
       }
     }

   int main()
   {
    pthread_t first;
    pthread_t second;
    pthread_t third;

    int hndl_first;
    int hndl_second;
    int hndl_third;

    hndl_first = pthread_create(&first, NULL, first_reader, NULL);
    hndl_second= pthread_create(&second, NULL, second_thread, NULL);
    hndl_third;= pthread_create(&third, NULL,third_thread, NULL);

   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0; 
   }
```

can i have any techniques to do this,or any simple example.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#attributes)

> attributes
>
> ```
> .n_rows           number of rows; present in Mat, Col, Row, Cube, field and SpMat
> .n_cols           number of columns; present in Mat, Col, Row, Cube, field and SpMat
> .n_elem           total number of elements; present in Mat, Col, Row, Cube, field and SpMat
> .n_slices             number of slices; present in Cube
> .n_nonzero            number of non-zero elements; present in SpMat
>
> Member variables which are read-only; to change the size, use .set_size(), .copy_size(), .zeros(), .ones(), or .reset()
> ```

So, do as they say, use

```
matrix.set_size(container.size(),50);
```

Comment: Thanks,jsantander, now now it works perfect with matrix.set_size(container.size(),50);.

Comment: Hi @kahsaykalayu if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like n_rows and n_cols members of matrix which you declared as **extern** is defined as a **constant** in arma namespace.